# Wicked pdf ignores decimal px

Tags: css, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to produce a pdf document. Everything is fine, except that Wicked PDF seems to completely ignore decimals when dealing with widths.

For example, if I set

```
body { letter-spacing: 1px; }
```

it works fine. However, if I put

```
body { letter-spacing: 0.3px; }
```

it falls back to `normal` or, in this case `0px`. If I try the exact same on browser, I get the desired result.

Is there a way to force wicked PDF to honour the decimal letter-spacing value?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, KJ, however it is useful to set character spacing and it is used widely in HTML

Comment: I ended up editing the font bearrings to successfully achieve the impossible atomic paradox which is, as it shouldn't, limited by inapplicable, archaic axiomas